# how to add image at the center of LayerList android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

I am setting style to my splash screen activity and in style I am adding background gradient, Now I am trying to add image at the center of screen, actually just below the center of screen lets say 20dp below the center.
can any one tell me how I can active it.

Style I am adding to activity:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">
            @drawable/background_splash
        </item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">
            @style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored
        </item>
        <item name="colorAccent">
            @color/white
        </item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">
            @color/blue.dark
        </item>
    </style>
```

background_splash.xml: please refer comment in file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splash_screen_gradient" /> 
// here I want to add Image here such that it will be we wrap_contect and
// 20dp below center of screen
</layer-list>
```

splash_screen_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="#ff0000"
                android:endColor="#00ff00"
                android:startColor="#0000ff">
            </gradient>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I have tried several permutation combinations by adding Bitmap, Item background in layer list but its not working as expected.
I don't want to add it in layout xml file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try This, it works for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/splash_screen_gradient" />
    <item android:top="20dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can store image in drawawble and create an item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/splash_screen_gradient" /> 
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_image" />
</layer-list>
```